# Difference between Data Memory Barrier and Data Synchronization Barrier on ARM processor

Tags: c++, c, arm, memory-barriers

I'm controlling DMA using hardware registers and looking at others code at work I saw them to use data memory/synchronization barrier instructions (dmb() and dsb()) and then tried to read about them from [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0360e/BABFDDDG.html). Platform I'm using is ARM based architecture.

In code I seen them implemented like this:

```
/* Data Synchronization Barrier */
#define dsb() __asm__ __volatile__ ("dsb" : : : "memory")

/* Data Memory Barrier */
#define dmb() __asm__ __volatile__ ("dmb" : : : "memory")
```

What is the difference between the two? I cannot make out the difference.

Comment: Based on reading the paragraphs in what you linked, the DMB ensures that memory operations started in program order have completed, but doesn't ensure that other out-of-order operations have completed. DSB seems to make sure that all transfers have completed, so all changes are visible in the state you would expect in program order.

Comment: Pragmatically DMB is typically used for 'software only' memory; normal DRAM.  Where as DSB usually involves devices (memory not integrated with system cache).  DSB is a superset of DMB but is slower (in most/all cases).  For instance, a cache flush wants a `DMB` at the start to make sure all previous writes are committed to the cache and not in the CPU pipeline.  Then after the flush, you want to do a `DSB` as the CP15 registers take time to complete and the flush will not necessarily be over by the time the `MCR` has completed.  You can gang several CP15 writes together with just one `DSB`.

Comment: So a compiler barrier make sure things aren't in registers.  A DMB makes sure things are committed to a cache or memory (not in a CPU load/store pipeline).  A DSB makes sure that even non-memory (load/store) instructions are complete.  Like MCR, MSR (co-processor and status registers)... and maybe some things I haven't thought of (branch prediction, SMC, etc), but at least this gives a better idea than answers in the duplicate.  Your macros have an implicit compiler barrier as well.

Comment: A compiler barrier will not prevent that loads and stores end up in registers. An ISA like ARM is a load/store architecture which means that regular instructions like an ADD can't access memory directly; it needs to be loaded in a register first. What compiler barriers will prevent is that loads/stores are removed due to code optimization.